# Arch linux: find missing fonts and installing them

Tags: arch-linux, x11, firefox, fonts

I use firefox in i3wm on arch linux and I often find pages with broken fonts.
It looks like this:

[image: broken font screenchot]

How can I find which font am I missing and how to install them ?

Thank you for help

Comment: You should try `noto-fonts`, `noto-fonts-cjk`, `noto-fonts-emoji`, and `noto-fonts-extra`. That should cover pretty much what you can ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @x80486 suggested, solution was to install `noto-fonts`, `noto-fonts-cjk`, `noto-fonts-emoji`, and `noto-fonts-extra` packages.

It can by done by running this commapnd:

```bsh
sudo pacman -S noto-fonts noto-fonts-cjk noto-fonts-emoji noto-fonts-extra
```

Comment: Thank you! In my minimal Arch container, the graphical Qt-based *featherpad* text editor only showed blocks instead of correct glyphs characters. To keep the download size small, and as I only require latin characters, it was enough to install the `noto-fonts` package. Though `noto-fonts-1:23.9.1-1` still has a 27.01 MiB download size and 106.95 MiB installed size.